# Ssh tunnel Node.js to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ssh

I have installed ssh2 in order to be able to connect from my Node.js server to MongoDB. First, when I run the code provided by documentation I take this Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cpu-features' in 'C:\Users\chris\Desktop\abot\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol' and this
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './crypto/build/Release/sshcrypto.node' in 'C:\Users\chris\Desktop\abot\node_modules\ssh2\lib\protocol'
With a little resarch I understand that this module not found errors are for optional modules and do not have some impact. Second, I am trying to connect with this code provided by the documentation:

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2');

const conn = new Client();

conn.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.forwardOut('my local ip', 8000, '127.0.0.1', 27017, (err, stream) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.on('close', () => {
        console.log('TCP :: CLOSED');
        conn.end();
      }).on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('TCP :: DATA: ' + data);
      }).end([
        'HEAD / HTTP/1.1',
        'User-Agent: curl/7.27.0',
        'Host: 127.0.0.1',
        'Accept: */*',
        'Connection: close',
        '',
        ''
      ].join('\r\n'));
    });
  }).connect({
    host: 'ip of the mongo server',
    port: ssh port,
    username: 'my user name',
    password: 'my password'
  });
```

Let me note that the server is configured to connect without providing the public key.
When I am running the code, I take these messages:
Client :: ready
TCP :: CLOSED

Note number 2. I can connect with ssh tunnel through python, but now I need to connect through node also but without results.